# regex OR condition matches both cases if we have both the words in the string

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am doing a lookahead **.*(?=foo|bar)** and finding if any one of the below word exist. Using OR condition, but its not stopping at the first match, even its matching the other condition as well

Below is the content which I am trying to parse. Content will have 2 formats. One with both foo AND bar, another with only foo OR bar. In fist case it should stop at the foo itself.

```
Testing 1.0

----------------------------------------

       foo:                1.0

     Some Text          

 bar:      1.5

----------------------------------------
```

another format

```
Testing 1.0

----------------------------------------


 bar:      1.5

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: where is your *code*?

Comment: just now highlighted in bold    .*(?=foo|bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lazy Quantifier**

Make it a lazy match:

```
.*?(?=foo|bar)
```

The `*` quantifier is greedy, so that `.*` matches to the end of the string. The engine then backtracks only as far back as needed to allow the lookahead to match—giving us the **longest match**.

In contrast, the `?` makes the `*` quantifier "lazy" or "reluctant", so that the `.*?` only matches as far as necessary—giving us the **shortest match**.

**Reference**

- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: BTW, look-ahead is really not needed here I guess?

Comment: @RohitJain A lookahead is needed if he wants to match up to the `foo`, but without including the `foo` in the match.

Comment: FYI: Added explanation and reference. :)

Comment: @zx81 - yep.. you are right.. Making it lazy will fix the problem.. :) .. +1